# Angularjs Directive with Isolated Scope doesn't trigger DOM change outside of directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, directive

I'm playing around angular directives with isolated scopes.
I've just faced an interesting situation. When I call a function from the local scope, which changes a $scope variable content, this is not affecting the DOM. In my example, I add a new element to the $scope.customers list, and this is not triggering the ngRepeat, so this part of the DOM is not affected where the ngRepeat items should be rendered.

Directive code:

```
function addItem() {
    scope.add();
        items.push({
        name: 'New Directive Customer'
    });
    scope.$broadcast("refresh");
    render();
}
...
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope: {
      datasource: '=',
      add: '&',
    },
    link: link
};
```

Local function code:

```
$scope.addCustomer = function() {
    counter++;
    $scope.customers.push({
        name: 'New Customer' + counter,
        street: counter + ' Cedar Point St.'
    });

    alert($scope.customers.length);
};
```

DOM ngRepeat part:

```
<isolate-scope-with-controller datasource="customers" add="addCustomer()"></isolate-scope-with-controller>
<hr />
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="customer in customers">{{customer.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The `alert()` will show that the `$scope.customers` is bigger after every button click, but the ngRepeat won't work on the DOM.

The full code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/8tUzKbKxK0twJsB6i104

My question is that, is this possible to trigger the DOM changes from this kind of directives somehow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plunkr only worked for me after removing the check for event.srcElement.id in the directive's click-callback.

```
 function addItem() {
      //Call external function passed in with &
      scope.add();

      //Add new customer to the local collection
      items.push({
          name: 'New Directive Customer'
      });


      scope.$broadcast("refresh");
      render();
  }
```

In the controller you have to use $scope.$apply to make the changes appear in the template:

```
    $scope.addCustomer = function() {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        counter++;
        $scope.customers.push({
          name: 'New Customer' + counter,
          street: counter + ' Cedar Point St.'
        });

    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lGmGiPIqEm2AA8cngkHz?p=preview

Comment: In Chrome this code worked for me. But in the case of question the $scope.$apply() solved my issue. Many thanks.